# Laravel 4 - Resource - Trying to return view from subfolder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've just started using Laravel 4 and I have a resource called "OrderController" with the following code:

```
 public function index()
 {
     return View::make('order.index');
 }
```

In my views folder I have a folder called "order" with a file called "index.blade.php" in it

Can you see anything wrong with this code as when I visit /order (this is mapping to the "OrderContoller") I get the following error:

```
Error in exception handler: The stream or file "/Users/Dave/Sites/test_website/app/storage/logs/log-apache2handler-2013-06-16.txt" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Users/Dave/Sites/test_website/bootstrap/compiled.php:7259
```

routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('index');

});

Route::resource('order', 'OrderController');
```

Any ideas?

It works using any views directly in the "views" folder, but I get that error if using a subfolder in the views folder.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Try check for your order folder permissions, is it readable?

Comment: Hi Guy, yes, it is readable (755)

Comment: Sorry, the error is on the logs dir, it should be read/write as well, is it so?

Comment: ive changed the "logs" directory to 755 and now get a different error: file_put_contents(/Users/Dave/Sites/test_website/app/storage/views/0863206947321983d8b8cdb1e7603cb2): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: ok...so i though I would carry on without sub folders for the time being..but looks like I still get same error when using views directly in the view folder (apart from when using index.blade.php?).

I tried using order-index.blade.php and still get the same error...this is a really silly problem to be having :(

Comment: actually im getting this error:

    file_put_contents(/Users/Dave/Sites/test_site/app/storage/views/701eef734201ec6b717842e77b7d3a1f): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: you need to to allow read/write on all of the storage dir and also delete everything under views to let it regenerate.

Comment: brilliant! works now...thanks very much @Guy :)

Answer (score 2):

Taking the answer from the comments, since it worked for me. If you're getting this type of error:

> Error in exception handler: The stream or file "/Users/Dave/Sites/test_website/app/storage/logs/log-apache2handler-2013-06-16.txt" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Users/Dave/Sites/test_website/bootstrap/compiled.php:7259

CHMOD every file in the storage folder to `777`. I did that in FileZilla.

Or go to the `app` folder in your command line and write:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
```